# Multiple Activities vs. One activity and multiple Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

What are the Pro/Cons of using multiple Activities vs having one Activity and displaying multiple Fragments? It seems to me FragmentTransactions are way more flexible than Activities and with the android-support-v4 lib it's all well supported. Anything I'm missing?